# Accessing image needs authentification

Tags: html, image, url, authentication, webserver

I recently made a Ruby on Rails app that parses and extracts a atom feed. I extract some fields like: person name, message and avatar-image link.

The problem is that the link for the avatar looks like this:

`https://foo.atlassian.net/secure/useravatar?ownerId=foo.bar&avatarId=10302&s=48`

If i'm logged on on the site from which I got the url for the image and I access the url in my browser, the image shows up. If I end the session (log out, open in other browser in which i'm not logged in etc.) it doesn't show up (actually it shows a default-no-avatar image).

How can I send some information to the server so I can authenticate and get the desired image? (I don't want to store the images - and I have a dummy account that I can use to authenticate).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Net::HTTP` with SSL. Example taken from the [Ruby STDLib Docs](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#label-HTTPS):

```
uri = URI('https://secure.example.com/some_path?query=string')

Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port, :use_ssl => uri.scheme == 'https').start do |http|
  request = Net::HTTP::Get.new uri.request_uri
  response = http.request request # Net::HTTPResponse object
  response.body # The actual response body
end
```